# Why does div#foo hr:first-child not work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I feel like this should work, if you can say #foo p:first-child why does #foo hr:first-child not work. If anyone can explain this one I'd really appreciate it.

I've setup a JSFiddle demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/mGu7x/6/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of the `<hr>` elements are the first-child of their parent element.

See [this updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mGu7x/7/) which makes the border more obvious and moves the hr to the top.

You might want to look at [`:first-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) which is new in CSS 3 and does what you appear to be looking for. (Can I Use [suggests that it has wide support](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-of-type) outside of non-current-IE).

See [a demo using `:first-of-type`](http://jsfiddle.net/mGu7x/8/) (which I have only tested in Chrome).

Comment: Yeah, that's how `:first-of-type` is intended to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Because `#main`'s `first-child` is a `p`, not an `hr`.

You can use [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) though:

```
#main hr:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}
```